# convert number with coma to normal number in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, converters

Asalamu alaikom
Hi evryone , hope you are fine .
i want to ask if there is a way to convert this number 10.33 to 11 with javascript 
and im sorry for my bad english

Comment: if you take care with your terminology you will have a far better time finding stuff yourself. You don't want to convert the number, you want to -round- the number up. Basic math terminology. A google for 'javascript round number' will provide you all the answers you need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: sorry but iam bad at english thats why i asked here. i didnt knew what is the exact expression that i should use to solve my probleme

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you search using your native language, you will also find out.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Math.ceil(10.33)
```

Will convert it to 11

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.ceil(10.33);
```

Will convert it to 11

Comment: No. Math.round() will round to the nearest integer. Ie it will round down if the first digit after the comma is less then 5 and round up if it is greater than five

Comment: TAking back my downvote as you corrected your answer ...